# GetHdfs to PutEmail Flow Apache NiFi

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

I am curious if I will need any extra processors for a GETHDFS - > COUNT PUTEMAIL flow using Apache Nifi.
I will be reading a CSV file from a HDFS location and I want to email the contents of the the directory using the PUTEMAIL.

i

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the contents of the FlowFile as the email message body, then you need to extract the contents to an attribute which can be done using the `ExtractText` processor.

Otherwise, you don't need any other processor. You can just use the FlowFile as an attached file and you're done.